# Here's an old school IF statement for you, but there is a problem

Tags: qbasic

I have an IF statement in QBASIC... yes... QBASIC...

I have been teaching someone to program (I decided this would be nice and easy to see
how the syntax works).

...Anyway, I have this code:

```
CLS

start:
INPUT ">>", a$

PRINT a$
IF (INSTR(a$, "do you")) THEN
    IF (INSTR(a$, "like")) THEN
        IF (INSTR(a$, "cheese")) THEN PRINT "Yep, I like cheese":
        IF (INSTR(a$, "music")) THEN PRINT "Depends, which genre?": GOTO musicGenre
    ELSE IF (INSTR(a$, "hate")) THEN
            IF (INSTR(a$, "cheese")) THEN PRINT "No, I like cheese"
        END IF
    END IF
END IF


musicGenre:
INPUT ">>", m$
SELECT CASE (m$)
    CASE "pop"
        PRINT "..pop! lol, baa baa"
    CASE "rock"
        PRINT "Rock is ok"
END SELECT
GOTO start
```

But when I type "`do you like cheese?`" it seems to only reply "`Yep, I like cheese`" every other time...

Could anyone shed some light on this?

**note:**

"`do you like music?`" works *every* time...

**note 2:**

Screenshot of the output:
[image]

Comment: What is the incorrect output you see when you input "do you like cheese?" and it doesn't say "Yep, I like cheese"?

Comment: What does it say when it doesn't say "Yep, I like cheese"  as expected? Anything, or nothing?

Comment: Nothing it goes back to the input prompt. (cheers @halfdan)

Comment: InStr returns an index as far as I know... Are you sure that the value it returns on failure is evaluated as false? I don't know QBasic, but I did stuff in VB6...

Comment: Is it exactly every other time or apparently somewhat random.  My first thought is make sure you aren't misspelling your input.

Comment: @apirogov - The index recieved is `13`

Comment: You are using input to parse cheese then a second input which does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code you provided appears correct.

Try one of the following:

- If possible, send us a larger code sample.  I'm guessing the error is outside the code you provided.
- Output the input (`a$`) before the first `IF` to confirm your code will be working with the expected input.
- In most languages, `FALSE` is zero and true is anything else.  However, you may want to be more explicit with the following `IF (INSTR(a$) > 0)`.

**EDIT:** You should put a `goto start` on any cheese result.  Otherwise, it's going to the `musicGenre` code.

Comment: Hey, cheers very much. a$ outputs as "`do you like cheese`" **however**, it won't even output the a$ afterwards.. like.. the output is right the first time, then it is empty (including the outputted a$) the second time, then it's correct the third.

Answer (score 2):

```
CLS

start:
    INPUT ">>", a$

    IF (INSTR(1, a$, "do you")) THEN
        IF (INSTR(1, a$, "like")) THEN
            IF (INSTR(1, a$, "cheese")) THEN PRINT "Yep, I like cheese"
            IF (INSTR(1, a$, "music")) THEN PRINT "Depends, which genre?": GOSUB musicGenre
        END IF
    IF (INSTR(1, a$, "hate")) THEN
        IF (INSTR(1, a$, "cheese")) THEN PRINT "No, I like cheese"
    END IF
END IF

GOTO start
musicGenre:
    INPUT ">>", m$
    SELECT CASE (m$)
        CASE "pop"
            PRINT "..pop! lol, baa baa"
        CASE "rock"
            PRINT "Rock is ok"
    END SELECT
RETURN
```

Comment: Code without any explanation isn't an acceptable answer here. Please [edit] to provide some information about **how** your code solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This program demonstrates parsing input and gosubs in Basic.

```
REM Cheese progran source:
CLS
DO
    INPUT ">>", a$
    a$ = LCASE$(a$)
    PRINT a$
    IF INSTR(a$, "do you") THEN
        IF INSTR(a$, "like") THEN
            IF INSTR(a$, "cheese") THEN
                PRINT "Yep, I like cheese":
            END IF
            IF INSTR(a$, "music") THEN
                PRINT "Depends, which genre?"
                GOSUB MusicGenre
            END IF
        ELSE
            IF INSTR(a$, "hate") THEN
                IF INSTR(a$, "cheese") THEN
                    PRINT "No, I like cheese"
                END IF
            END IF
        END IF
    END IF
LOOP
END
MusicGenre:
INPUT ">>>", m$
a$ = LCASE$(a$)
SELECT CASE (m$)
    CASE "pop"
        PRINT "..pop! lol, baa baa"
    CASE "rock"
        PRINT "Rock is ok"
END SELECT
RETURN
```